# Filter typenames in C++

Tags: c++, templates, reinterpret-cast, typename

This is my converter to byte array (vector).

```
template<typename T>
void put(T value) {
    int size = sizeof(value);

    uint8_t *array;
    array = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&value);

    if (littleEndian) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr.push_back(array[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arr.push_back(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this function accepts all variable types. Is it possible to filter typenames? E.g. I want to allow only `uint8_t, int8_t, uint16_t, int16_t etc. + float and double too`? I don't want to make 10 `if` statements, because it doesn't look clean.

Comment: What is the point to declare and assign value to `array` in different statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) and SFINAE.  This will remove the template from consideration if the type is not a integer type.  It would look something like

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void put(T value)
{
    // code
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2997058890f9a79e)</kbd>

If instead you want allow all integral and floating point types then you can use [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) like

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void put(T value)
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add float and double?

Comment: @SzymonMarczak If you want integers and floating point types then you want to use [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic)

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a function that accept only any integral types.

There is an existing type trait for that un the [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header called [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral). You can use it with `std::enable_if` to produce the expected constraint:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, int> = 0>
void put(T value) {
    constexpr int size = sizeof(value);

    uint8_t *array;
    array = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&value);

    if (littleEndian) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr.push_back(array[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arr.push_back(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Your function is now not callable with non integral types.

Be aware that if there's another overload of the function, the compiler will try it too. That means that if you have another function that accept any floating types, the compiler will select the appropriated overload.